# Генератор рандомных картинок

Tags: swift, swift3

У меня есть несколько картинок например : "Avatar1.png", "Avatar2.png" ...
Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку `UIImageView` менял свою картинку на другую - случайную.

Пробовал такой код, но при запуске страница вообще не запускается:

```
@IBAction func avatarsButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        randomImage.image = UIImage(named: "Avatar\(arc4random_uniform(4) + 1).png")
 }
```

Comment: Куда размещали картинки?

Comment: Есть два ViewController на первом инфа о юзерах, на втором добавить еще одного и там типа фотка и при нажатии на кнопку должна ставится случайная аватарка

Comment: Я имею в виду в проекте.

Comment: если вместо выбора картинки сделать просто установку одной картинки работает? randomImage.image = UIImage(named: "Avatar1.png")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 3:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var avatar: UIImageView!
let avatars = ["Avatar1.png","Avatar2.png","Avatar3.png"] // массив с названиями аватарок


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func changeAvatarPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    avatar.image = UIImage(named: avatars[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(avatars.count)))]) // рандомно присваиваем UIImageView один из аватаров из маассива avatars
}

}
```

Естественно, что картинки необходимо подключить к проекту в **Assets.xcassets**, но это уже другая история)

Надеюсь, что я Вам помог. Удачи Вам во всех ваших начинаниях!